# something wrong with array updating multiply results

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli

I have table with 10 records and 2 inputs in each.
I made post for it and used array but i do something wrong but cant figure out what.What i m trying to do is update many rows at time!
I still learning php array

POST

```
    if($source == 'hoursDayNight'){
    $value      = htmlentities($_POST['value'], ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
    $workcid      = htmlentities($_POST['workcid'][$i], ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
    $worknight      = htmlentities($_POST['worknight'][$i], ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
    $workday      = htmlentities($_POST['workday'][$i], ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
    include('inc.php');     

    //$current_dateedit = date('Y-m-d == H:i:s');
    $current_dateedit = date('Y-m-d');
$i=NULL;
$i=1;

    $queryie = "UPDATE works SET workday='".$workday[$i]."', worknight='".$worknight[$i]."', type='1'  WHERE id='" . $workcid[$i] . "'";
    mysqli_query($conn, $queryie);

}
```

and table

```
                        <form name="hoursDayNight" method="POST" action="" >
                <input type="hidden" name="source" value="hoursDayNight"/>
                    <table class="ui small sortable celled collapsing table">
                        <thead> 
                            <tr>
                                <th>Worker</th>
                                <th>Day h</th>
                                <th>Night h</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                    <tbody>';

            require('inc.php');     
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT * FROM works WHERE worker = '".$row['person_code']."'";
                    $i=null;
                    $i++;

                      echo '<tr>
                            <input type="text" name="" disabled value="' . $row['worker'] . '">
                                <input type="hidden" name="workcid['.$i.']" value="' . $row['id'] . '">

                            <input type="text" style="width: 25px; border: 1px solid #C8CFD7; height: 16px; line-height:14px; text-align: center; font-size:10pt; color:#817e7f;" name="workday['.$i.']" value="' . $row['workday'] . '">



                            <td>


                            <input type="text" style="width: 25px; border: 1px solid #C8CFD7; height: 16px; line-height:14px; text-align: center; font-size:10pt; color:#817e7f;" name="worknight['.$i.']" value="' . $row['worknight'] . '">

                            </div>

                            </form>
```

Comment: It would be easier to help you if you explained exactly what the problem was. But one thing I can see is that you're explicitly setting `$i = 1` in your code, so it will only be that row that gets updates.

Comment: it dont do any thing. no errors and no data saved

Comment: Be more specific. Is your PHP code being called at all? If so, check what the parameters that are being passed to it are - are they what they're supposed to be? Add some debugging to your code to see what the queries you're generating look like - do they look OK? Do they run when you try them directly in the database?

Comment: I answered my question!Thanks everyone that tired to help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it working :)

Code:

```
if($source == 'hoursDayNight'){
$value      = htmlentities($_POST['value'], ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
$records=htmlentities($_POST['records'], ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
include('inc.php'); 
$i = null;      
while ($i <= $records){
$i++;
$workday = $worknight = $workcid = null;
$workcid      = htmlentities($_POST['workcid'][$i], ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
$worknight      = htmlentities($_POST['worknight'][$i], ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
$workday      = htmlentities($_POST['workday'][$i], ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");

$queryie = UPDATE works SET workday='".$workday[$i]."', worknight='".$worknight[$i]."', type='1'  WHERE id='" . $workcid[$i] . "'";
mysqli_query($conn, $queryie);

}
}
```

Table:

```
                        <form name="hoursDayNight" method="POST" action="" >
        <input type="hidden" name="source" value="hoursDayNight"/>
                <table class="ui small sortable celled collapsing table">
                    <thead> 
                        <tr>
                        <th>Worker</th>
                        <th>Day h</th>
                        <th>Night h</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                <tbody>';


                                        require('inc.php');
                $i=null;                
                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT f_name, l_name FROM n_employees WHERE navWorkerID = '".$row['person_code']."'";
                $query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
                $rs = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC );
                if ($view){$workeris1="&worker=".$row['person_code']."";}else{$workeris1 = NULL;}

        echo '<tr>';




        $i++;                               

        <input type="hidden" name="records" value="'.$i.'"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="workcid['.$i.']" value="' . $row['id'] . '">

        <input type="text" style="width: 25px; border: 1px solid #C8CFD7; height: 16px; line-height:14px; text-align: center; font-size:10pt; color:#817e7f;" name="workday['.$i.']" value="' . $row['workday'] . '">
        <td>

        <input type="text" style="width: 25px; border: 1px solid #C8CFD7; height: 16px; line-height:14px; text-align: center; font-size:10pt; color:#817e7f;" name="worknight['.$i.']" value="' . $row['worknight'] . '">

        </div>

        </form>
```

Sorry for mess still learning to put everything with style :D

Answer (score -1):

I don't think you'll have to put the 'workid', 'workday' and 'worknight' name attribute as an array with keys in the input tags. I think that's where the problem is coming from. try something like `<input name="workid[]" .. />`, or `<input name="workday[]".. />`. And also there is nothing in the name attribute of $row['worker'], that can prevent you from getting the value.

Also use:

```
if(isset($_POST['hoursDayNight'])){ 
$i=0;
//process form
$++;
}
```

to process that form intead of:

```
if($source == 'hoursDayNight'){
//process form
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If there is no record with

> id = $workcid[1]

then mysql has nothing to update and that is no error.